# How to specify tuple type in anonymous functions in scala

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming, tuples

I have a function called `map_tree` as follows:

```
def fold_tree[A,B](f1: A => B) (f2: (A,B,B) => B) (t: Tree[A]) : B = t match {
    case Leaf(value) => f1(value)
    case Node(value , l, r) => f2 (value, fold_tree (f1) (f2) (l), fold_tree (f1) (f2) (r) )
  }
```

and I need to implement a function called `right_most` that takes a `Tree[A]` and returns `A`. Here's my attempt at it:

```
def right_most [A](t:Tree[A]) : A =
    fold_tree ((x: A) => x) ((v: (A, A, A)) => v._3) (t)
```

But I get the following errors:

```
 found   : ((A, A, A)) => A
 required: (A, A, A) => A
    fold_tree ((x: A) => x) ((v: (A, A, A)) => v._3) (t)
                                            ^
one error found
```

Looks to me like found and required are the same. What's the error then? Additionally, how do we specify the tuple type in anonymous functions? And why do I need to specify the tuple type in the function signature. Can't scala infer it?

Comment: what is `fold_tree` definition?

Comment: sorry, accidentally included map_tree. Replaced it with fold_tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala compiler can infer lot of things for you. so, do this

```
def right_most [A](t:Tree[A]) : A =
    fold_tree[A, A](_) ((_, _, c) => c) (t)
```

You got compilation error because you were using f2 params like triplet (tuples). Instead you need function params  like this `( (a, b, c) => c )`

Comment: f2's function parameters is a tuple right? So how come

`def right_most [A](t:Tree[A]) : A =
    fold_tree((x: A) => x) ((v: Tuple3[A,A,A]) => v._3) (t)`

doesn't pass as well

Comment: @VarunPatro ... function params cannot be used as tuples